# WebAPI on same server, can it be accessed over http instead of https even though SSL applied on it?

Tags: performance, ssl, asp.net-web-api

I have WebAPP and WEBAPI on same server. I have applied SSL certificate on both the sites under same server (both are separate applications under common IIS default website).

Now my point, Can I access same WEBAPI over http instead of https form 3rd intranet application on same server and which is not a secure application?

My intention to not hamper performance for 3rd site which is not secured and on the same server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually It depends on your configuration.

Generally, when you apply `SSL` on web server your app can now be accessed over `http` and `https` both connections.

But, if you have configured it to redirect `http` version to `https` using `CSP` or server end configuration, then you can access `http` version as all requests will get automatically redirected to `https` version.

Comment: Atul Thanks for your reply, Can you just brief me on how CSP or server end configuration to allows http and https?

Comment: `https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaushal/2013/05/22/http-to-https-redirects-on-iis-7-x-and-higher/` `https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/encrypt-in-transit/enable-https` these links might be helpful .

Comment: if default port 80 already used for some other app then we have to add binding configuration Non-SSL port, In my case default port was already in used for other application, need to expose port for non-SSL operation from binding configuration

Answer (score 0):

You should read IIS related materials to learn what is site binding. A web site can of course contain multiple bindings, both HTTP and HTTPS, so that clients (like web browsers) can access using both http:// and https://.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/chrad/2010/01/24/understanding-iis-bindings-websites-virtual-directories-and-lastly-application-pools/